# How can I toast a message after load item in recyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

There are limited items(fro example 5 items) that I want to show them in recyclerview.These items don't need to scrolling and all of them will show once time.I want to toast a message after load each item in recyclerview(not scrolling).How can I do that?

Comment: items load, after you scroll the recyclerView

Comment: please elaborate what you want

Comment: Do it in method `getAdapter` in your adapter.

Comment: @PouyaHeydari If I have few items for example 3 items it doesn't need to scroll

Comment: Can you explain it better please?

Comment: so if you have 3 or less items, put your toast code in onBindViewHolder

Comment: @PouyaHeydari I want code it in activity or fragment not in adapter class.Is there some thing like addOnScrollListener(but not scrolling (-; )?

Comment: what language are you using? kotlin or java? tell me, then I'll post the answer for you ;)

Comment: @PouyaHeydari java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make an interface. to do so :

1. make this interface:

   ```
    public interface OnLoadInterface {
     void onLoad();
     }
   ```
2. implement this code in your activity or fragment :

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
   OnLoadInterface
   ```
3. override onLoad method in your activity or fragment and add desiered code
4. in your adapter :

   ```
   OnLoadInterface onLoadInterface;
   Adapter(OnLoadInterface onLoadInterface) {
   this.onLoadInterface = onLoadInterface;
   }
   ```
5. in your onCreateViewHolder :

   ```
   @Override
   public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
   View view = 
   LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_main,parent,false);
   return new MyViewHolder(view,onLoadInterface);
    }
   ```

6.in your ViewHolder (Named MyViewHolder here) call this line after             `super(itemView)` :

```
    OnLoadInterface.onLoad();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement Toast in onBindViewHolder method.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int 
position) {    

    Toast t = Toast.makeText(context, Integer.toString(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    t.show();
}
```

define context variable

```
Context context
```

in the constructor pass current context

```
Context context;
public RecyclerAdapter(Context context) {       
    this.context = context;
}
```